# Boolean Comparison

Tags: comparison, scheme, boolean, computer-science, boolean-expression

I'm doing a few exercises from HtDP (How to Design Programs) and I am kind of stuck on the Boolean comparison question. It goes like this.

```
    (define b1 true)

    (define b2 false)
```

Write an expression that computes whether b1 is false and b2 is true. If false produce No and vice versa.

Right now this is all I have come up with:

```
   (and b1 true) => true
```

(Shameless. I know but I am new at this and I am really slow to catch on)

Any help you could give me would be match appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty straightforward to translate the question into code. As a first approach, let's copy the question verbatim in pseudocode:

```
(b1 == false) AND (b2 == true)
```

Now, how would you write the above in Scheme? remember, Scheme uses prefix notation

```
(<???> (<???> b1 false) (<???> b2 true))
```

With a bit more of practice, the same code can be written more compactly like this (again, first in pseudocode):

```
NOT b1 AND b2
```

Which should be simple enough to write in Scheme:

```
(<???> (<???> b1) b2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the HtDP way of writing expressions, but you can write a simple truth table and find the boolean expression:

b1 | b2 | Y

0 |  0 | 0

0 |  1 | 1

1 |  0 | 0

1 |  1 | 0

hence Y = (NOT b1) AND b2 => TRUE